# Extra text with HTML Tables in R Studio

Tags: html, r, xtable

Using the R Html script in R Studio I'm trying to insert a table, however when I knit the file together I get 16 rows of ## before the table shows up. I have echo=FALSE and message = FALSE set. Here's what it looks like:

> [image]

What else am I missing?

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is my table: </p>

<!--begin.rcode,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='markup'
library(xtable)
df1 <- data.frame(
   group = factor(rep(c("C", "G"), 5)),
   value = 1:10)

df1 <- xtable(df1, caption = "Table 1")

print (df1,include.rownames = FALSE, caption.placement = "top", type="html")
end.rcode-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change to `results='asis'`

Comment: Well don't I feel silly. I played around with every other combination, guess I missed that one. Thanks.